# Locking JPA entity hierarchy being updated massively from MDB's in cluster

Tags: java, jpa, concurrency, locking

I need some help in the following situation: imagine a hierarchy of `Job` entities that have a `progress` attribute. Some jobs consist of multiple subjobs making a job tree. The progress of these composite jobs is calculated from their subjobs. The bottom jobs progresses are updated periodically and then the whole tree's progress is recalculated bottom-up. Job progresses are updated via JMS messages received. In this case the job is fetched via JPA from the database and the progress is modified and a recursive recalculation is started.

How should I deal with locking if this runs in a cluster? I would like to avoid situations when two subjobs are updated from 0% to 100% and the parent job goes to 50% instead of 100% as both the updates see 0%, 100% and vica versa.

My first thought was using synchronization on the job objects. But this is not ok, because multiple runtime objects may represent the same record in the database.

Could you suggest me a good, efficient way to handle this situation?